# Clicking on <button> shifts inner text in IE8/9 and Opera

Tags: css, internet-explorer, button, opera

I'm having trouble getting a  tag to react to a click the same way in all browsers. For some reason the  tag is shifting it's inner text down and to the right when clicked in IE 8/9 and Opera. This does not happen in the latest Firefox or Chrome.

http://codepen.io/jimmykup/pen/vEAyd

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `line-height` attribute and only use `width`, `height` and `padding` for the desired size.